# Passing data from Fragment to new Activity

Tags: java, android, arguments, fragment, bundle

I am trying to pass data from my Main Activity, to my Camera Activity, to my Camera Fragment, and then back to my Main Activity. I want the user to be able to save the information they input on the Main Activity to remain when they are finished using the camera.

On my **Main Activity**, I am passing the following as intent extras to the **Camera Activity**:

(NOTE: this works)

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("description" , editTextDescription.getText().toString());
    cameraIntent.putExtra("category" , editTextCategory.getText().toString());
    cameraIntent.putExtra("notes" , editTextNotes.getText().toString());
MainActivity.this.startActivity(cameraIntent);
```

I am then receiving the extras on my **Camera Activity** successfully, and passing them in a bundle to my **Camera Fragment**:

(NOTE: this works)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

     description = intent.getExtras().getString("description");
     category = intent.getExtras().getString("category");
     notes = intent.getExtras().getString("notes");

    }

if (null == savedInstanceState) {

    CameraFragment cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("description", description);
    bundle.putString("category", category);
    bundle.putString("notes", notes);
    cameraFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    Log.v(TAG, "Here is the bundle: " + bundle.toString());

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, cameraFragment.newInstance())
        .add(cameraFragment, bundle.toString())
        .commit();

    }
```

In my **Camera Fragment**, I am receiving the bundle in my **onCreateView** as follows:

(NOTE: this works)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (getArguments() != null) {

        description = getArguments().getString("description");
        category = getArguments().getString("category");
        notes = getArguments().getString("notes");
        Log.v(TAG, "Here are your arguments from the camera activity:  " + description + "  " + category + "  " + notes);

    } 

    else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Your arguments are null");
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
}
```

All of these transactions are properly executing, and I have received all of the information correctly up to this point. My goal now is to take the information, and pass it back to the **Main Activity**.

**ISSUE****

```
case R.id.doneButton: {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("description", description);
            intent.putExtra("category", category);
            intent.putExtra("notes", notes);
            Log.v(TAG, "Here are the extras going back to the Main Activity " + description + "  " + category + "  " + notes);
    startActivity(intent);
            break;

        }
```

However, I am unable to take the information I have received in my Fragment, and use the variables elsewhere. I have attempted trying to get the arguments in a method other than the **onCreateView**, and then use the method before passing the extras back to the **Main Activity**. I have also tried getting the arguments within my **onClick** switch, case method, however, when I try to send the data back to my **Main Activity**, it always returns null because it is not taking what it has received in the arguments, but instead using the Strings I have declared earlier.

```
private String description;
private String category;
private String notes;
```

Is there a way to take the data I have received in arguments in my **Camera Fragment**, and use them outside of the **onCreateView** method, and send them back to my **Main Activity**?

Comment: So are you saying that you are having description, category, and notes as null in your doneButton switch case?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a 'get' method in your Fragment .

```
cameraFragment.getXXXX();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of rewritten your code and this works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
        cameraIntent.putExtra("description" , "description");
        cameraIntent.putExtra("category" , "category");
        cameraIntent.putExtra("notes" , "notes");
        startActivity(cameraIntent);
    }
}

public class CameraActivity extends Activity{

    private String description,category,notes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

            description = intent.getExtras().getString("description");
            category = intent.getExtras().getString("category");
            notes = intent.getExtras().getString("notes");

        }

        if (null == savedInstanceState) {

            CameraFragment cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("description", description);
            bundle.putString("category", category);
            bundle.putString("notes", notes);
            cameraFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            Log.v(TAG, "Here is the bundle: " + bundle.toString());

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, cameraFragment)
                    .commit();

        }
    }
}
```

Even in the onClick of the doneButton the 3 strings are getting populated

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment{

    private String description,category,notes;
    private Button doneButton;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
        if (getArguments() != null) {

            description = getArguments().getString("description");
            category = getArguments().getString("category");
            notes = getArguments().getString("notes");
            Log.v("CameraFragment", "Here are your arguments from the camera activity:  " + description + "  " + category + "  " + notes);

        }

        else {
            Log.v("CameraFragment", "Your arguments are null");
        }
        doneButton = view.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("description", description);
                intent.putExtra("category", category);
                intent.putExtra("notes", notes);
                Log.v("CameraFragment", "Here are the extras going back to the Main Activity " + description + "  " + category + "  " + notes);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```